# I need for a cell in column "F" to clear when the training date has been updated in that same row in column "J"

Tags: excel, vba

I need for a cell in column "F" to clear content when the training date has been updated in that same row in column "J".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks many important details and is hard for others to reproduce. This means you are unlikely to get an answer as the question is posed now. I suggest you read our guide on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and about a [mcve] and then [edit] your question to provide information: (i) a *small* example for others to play around with, (ii) what you mean by "update", (iii) what other things exactly you tried and why it didn't work. (iv) are you sure this is related to VBA and not simple Excel formulas? If so, correct your question tag.

Comment: I removed the fact you tried other suggestions (which is irrelevant, especially since we don't know what suggestions you tried), and your signature+thanks, and you can now see that there's really not much posted regarding the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the worksheet's VBA (Click on that sheet in your VBAProject pane in VBE). Use the `Worksheet_Change()` event. That's an event, a chunk of code, that will execute whenever the worksheet changes. `Target` is a special variable here that will contain the range/cell that was changed when the code executes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Did something change in column J?
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J:J")) Is Nothing Then
        'Set the cell in Column F for the same row to nothing
        Range("F" & Target.Row).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: OMG!!!! Thank you so much! That worked straight out of the box. Thank you so much JNevill. Merry Christmas and I hope that you have a Wonderful New Year!  -  Angela